# Can we get declared properties of a Groovy class by its order?

Tags: groovy, properties

I created a plain Groovy class (i.e Person class)with some properties. Now I want to get those declared attributes (which I've defined in my class) with their order, but I don't know how to do it.
I've tried to use Person.metaClass.getProperties() but it retrieves not only declared properties but also built-in Groovy ones.
Could you please help me on this: just get declared properties by its order when declaring.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 10):

I can't see a use case, but the compiler could  reorder all fields declaration while creating bytecode. I'm pretty sure ordering is not a constraint on fields though it should mostly be the case for not modified/enhanced class

As per the JVM spec, generated fields should be marked SYNTHETIC (like generated methods) in the bytecode, so you can test with :

```
Person.getDeclaredFields().grep {  !it.synthetic }
```

and filter the base Groovy fields like ClassInfo,metaClass and others beginning by `__timestamp`

But I'm not a specialist, there could be another way I don't think of

Comment: +1 for `Person.declaredFields.grep { !it.synthetic }` -- handy! :-D

Answer (score 3):

There was a question about this on the [mailing list back in February of this year](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/how-to-get-map-of-bean-s-properties-in-original-order-instead-of-alphabetic-order-td3374040.html)

The answer is, no.  There is no way to get properties in the order they are declared in the class without doing some extra work.

1. You could parse the source file for the class, and generate an ordered list of property names from that
2. You could write a custom annotation, and annotate the fields with this annotation ie: `@Order(1) String prop`
3. You could make all of the classes where this matters implement an interface which forces them to have a method that returns the names of the properties in order.

Other than that, you probably want to have a re-think :-(

Comment: a quick search on "jvm spec field order" gave me [this link](http://code.google.com/p/javastruct/wiki/HowToUseJavaStruct) to weighten your point ;-)